# Move recently created files to another directory

Tags: shell

This is my shell script code:

```
FILE_NAMES=$(find . -mtime +0 -name "*" | awk '{printf("%s ", $x)}');
sudo gzip ${FILES_NAMES};
```

What is the third command to move recently created gzip files to another directory?

Comment: mv FILE1 DIRECTORY/

Comment: When the other dir is new, you can first move the files and then gzip them all (works best when all dirs are on in the same partition).

Comment: You assign to `FILE_NAMES` and then use `FILES_NAMES` - this cannot work.